# How to save SQLite table rows into an array?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have tried many different ways to do this, but basically when I get all of data from my database I want to store it in an array, but I do not know how to iterate through the index's as the data is read from the database. Here is how I am getting the data and adding it to the array:

```
public void makeObjects(){
    i =0;
    db.open();
    for(int j = 0; j< amount; j++)
    {
        objarray.add(o); 
    }

    Cursor c = db.fetchAllNotes();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {

        do {      

            objarray.get(i).setid(c.getString(0));
            objarray.get(i).settitle(c.getString(1));
            objarray.get(i).setinfo(c.getString(2));
            objarray.get(i).setlat(c.getString(3));
            objarray.get(i).setlon(c.getString(4));
            objarray.get(i).setmc(c.getString(5));

            i++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }



    db.close();

}
```

For testing and simplicity I have two rows in my database, I have a for loop which adds two new indexes to the array, but when I print out the contents of the array to the `logcat`, I see that both indexes have the last data to be read from the database, the second row twice. How can I make sure that row one enters index 0 and row two enters index 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new object for each element of your array to reference, rather than having them all reference the same object.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, could you show me how to do this please? This could take me a long time to figure out. Thank you!!!!

Comment: How are you initializing `o`? Probably, the right hand side of that initialization is what you should be using inside the first loop. Something like `objarray.add(new WhatEver());`

Comment: You were right, all this time I was missing this little piece of code and I tried everything but that! :( Thank you for noticing this and helping me solve this, it all works now, I will accept this as the answer once it allows me to! :)

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried many different ways to do this, but basically when I get
>   all of data from my database I want to store it in an array

What about to create **own Object** that presents table in your db? This Object will have some attributes which will present columns in table.

And here is algorithm how to save each row from db into List of Objects:

1. Fetch all rows into `Cursor`
2. Loop through `Cursor` and for each row create new Object and save it
   into List of Objects.

### Example:

```
public class Foo {

   private int id;
   private String name;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Now implementation of method:

```
public List<Foo> getAll() {
   List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
   Foo member = null;
   Cursor c = null;
   try {
      c = db.rawQuery("Select * from Table", null);
      if (c.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
            member = new Foo();
            member.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
            member.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            foos.add(member);
         } while (c.moveToNext());
      }
      return foos;
   }
   finally {
      if (c != null) {
         c.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy!! Thanks for your answer, I managed to fix it, I was missing a little piece of code all this time!! :( :) Excellent answer though, thank you I will keep this code!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might help you. This function reads the database and returns the row as an object. This function is wrtten in a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
ParamsBMI getTemplate(String strPersonName)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BMI_PARAMS, new String[] { KEY_PERSON_NAME, KEY_GENDER_MALE, KEY_DOB_YEAR, KEY_DOB_MOY, KEY_DOB_DOM, KEY_HEIGHT_UNIT, KEY_WEIGHT_UNIT, KEY_HEIGHT_CMS, KEY_HEIGHT_FT, KEY_HEIGHT_INCHES, KEY_WEIGHT_KGS,
            KEY_WEIGHT_POUNDS }, KEY_PERSON_NAME + "=?", new String[] { strPersonName }, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    ParamsBMI paramsBMI = new ParamsBMI();

    paramsBMI.setPersonName(cursor.getString(0));

    boolean bGenderMale = (cursor.getInt(1) == 1) ? true : false;
    paramsBMI.setGenderMale(bGenderMale);

    paramsBMI.setDOBYear(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
    paramsBMI.setDOBMonthOfYear(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
    paramsBMI.setDOBDayOfMonth(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));

    paramsBMI.setHeightUnit(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
    paramsBMI.setWeightUnit(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)));

    paramsBMI.setHeightCms(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(7)));
    paramsBMI.setHeightFt(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(8)));
    paramsBMI.setHeightInches(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(9)));

    paramsBMI.setWeightKgs(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(10)));
    paramsBMI.setWeightPounds(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(11)));

    return paramsBMI;
}
```